# Creating popup window and displaying data

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers

I'm moving from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 6 in my project.
In the OpenLayers 2 project when I click on a feature in a 
vector layer I get the description of the feature in a popup window.

Here is the code:

```
function createVectorLayer(layer) {
    var l = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(
        layer.Title,
        {
        eventListeners: {
            'featureselected': function (evt) {
                var f = evt.feature;
                var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                    //OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(f.geometry.toShortString()),// Michael commented 25/02/2018
                    OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(f.geometry.getCentroid().toShortString()),
                    null,
                    "<div style='font-size:.8em'>" + f.attributes.Description + "<br/><a href='#picturedFeatureEditor' class='ui-btn ui-mini' id='featureEditButton'>עדכון</a></div>",
                    null,
                    true
                );

                f.popup = popup;

                map.addPopup(popup);

                $("#featureEditButton").click(function () {
                    editableFeature = f.attributes;
                    editableFeatureObject = f;
                    initFeatureEditor();
                    //$.mobile.changePage("#picturedFeatureEditor");
                });
            },
            'featureunselected': function (evt) {
                var feature = evt.feature;
                map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                feature.popup.destroy();
                feature.popup = null;
            }
        },
        }
    );

    return l;
}
```

Here is how I create a Vector layer in OpenLayers 6:

```
    function createVectorLayer(layer) {
    var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        loader: dataServices.getFeatures(layer.Id,
            function (response) {
                if (!response) return;
                var features = [];
                $(response).each(function (i, j) {
                    let shapeObject = getShapeObject(j);
                    let feature = new ol.Feature({ 'geometry': shapeObject });
                    features.push(feature);
                });
                source.addFeatures(features);
            },
            function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessag) {
                console.log(errorMessag);
            })
    });

    return new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: createStyle(source)
    });
}
```

I know that I can create a popup using Overlay and ol.interaction.Select 
which is fired when the feature is clicked, but I don't know how to access the feature description when the feature is clicked to display it in the popup.

My question is how I can implement the same behaviour using OpenLayers 6 (i.e. how to implement feature popups in 6)?

Comment: I would listen to the 'singleclick' event and then used method 'forEachFeatureAtPixel' to sort out the features you want, and proceeded with adding the overlay if any conditions are met.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_MapBrowserEvent-MapBrowserEvent.html#event:singleclick

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel

Comment: @Koronag thanks for post what is the difference between ol.interaction.Select and forEachFeatureAtPixel?

Comment: The select interaction is an interaction added to the map. forEachFeatureAtPixel is just a method that checks if there are any features at the pixel provided. Listening to the singleclick event on the map you can extract the current pixel from the returned event (evt.pixel for example, if i don't remember incorrectly) and then check if there are any features at the given pixel with forEachFeatureAtPixel. If there is, you can then add the overlay popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add properties to the feature in the constructor (assuming the data is available from your `dataServices`):

```
                let feature = new ol.Feature({
                    geometry: shapeObject,
                    description: ....
                });
```

which can then be accessed using `feature.get('description')` or `feature.getProperties().description`

If you are using a Select interaction

```
select.on('select', function(event) {
  if (event.selected.length > 0) {
    var feature = event.selected[0];
    var description = feature.get('description');
  }
});
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the post. If I use ol.interaction.Select and on('select', function()) how can I access "description" property.or should I use 'singleclick' event and then method 'forEachFeatureAtPixel' as Koronag commented?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the ol-ext FeaturePopup.
See example: https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.feature.html
Or https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/map.popup.html